# 405 Not Allowed error when submitting html form to php file

Tags: php, html, forms, post, http-status-code-405

I'm building a website and like the title says, I have some issues with an html for that is supposed to POST to a php file to email the form input to my mailbox.
It looks like it's a common error but I can't find a reliable solution that applies to me. When I push submit I get a 405 not allowed nginx type of error.
Now before I post the code, I should add that I'm hosting on GitHub Pages for test purposes, can it be the reason why I get this error?
When I test locally, using MAMP, and try to submit, the browser (Chrome) opens the php file in plain text.

Here is my html form:

```
<div id="form">
    <form method="post" name="my_message_form" action="form-to-email.php">
        <p id="address_title">address</p>
        <input type="email" placeholder="your email address" name="sender_email">
        <p id="message_title">message</p>
        <textarea placeholder="type your message here..." rows="5" cols="80" name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="send_button" value="send">
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is my php file:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
header('Location: error_form.html');
}

$visitor_email = $_POST['sender_email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($visitor_email)) 
{
echo "I need your email to reply to you!";
exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'heuze.maxime@gmail.com';
$email_subject = "New message from your website";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $visitor_email.\n".
    "Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "heuze.maxime@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

If anyone can figure what's wrong it would greatly help my project, thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Are you running the url by putting it in a browser address bar, or using some sort of click on a file manager tool

Comment: the error is from your script check out this simple solution here:[source link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666234/using-php-to-send-form-to-my-email-having-an-issue-with-405-not-allowed-when-fo?rq=1)

Comment: Michael, I've already read that thread and I'm not sure what answer you're talking about? Mind being a little bit more specific?